# Velocity of a charged particle due to electric field in relativistic limit

Tags: relativistic-rocket, electromagnetism

I am trying to calculate the velocity of a charged particle moving through a constant E field.
I understand that I can set $\frac{1}{2}mv^{2} = qV$ to give $v = \sqrt{\frac{2Vq}{m}}$

However, im not sure how to expand this to relativistic limits since at the moment a higher voltage gives a higher and higher velocity.

I saw in another thread the equation:

$v^{2}(1+\frac{2Vq}{mc^{2}})=\frac{2Vq}{m}$

However I cant seem to get to get this result.

If anyone could help that would be great!

Comment: Relevance to space exploration?

Comment: What *none of the close voters mentioned* and you probably didn't know is that there are [almost 200 Stack Exchange sites to choose from](https://stackexchange.com/sites#newest)! Perhaps this will be migrated to [Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/). If not you can consider asking there yourself, this seems like a reasonable question, but they'll probably ask you to 1) cite or give the links to those places where you saw those equations, and 2) explain what you've tried yourself beyond searching for the questions.